# Gerrit filter for items I need to review

Tags: gerrit

I'm trying to create a search query which will tell me open changes which I am added to as a reviewer, but which I haven't submitted a code review for the latest patchset. This should include changes which other people have given a review for, but I have not.

The closest I could find was `is:reviewer AND -is:reviewed AND status:open`, but this doesn't include changes which other people have reviewed but I have not.

Comment: What version of gerrit are you using?

Comment: @TomKelly, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

A late reply, but for anyone looking for an answer to this you can filter out uploads where you have given a review score by appending below to your query.

```
is:reviewer AND is:open AND NOT label:Code-Review>=-2,userid
```

Where userid is replaced with your user id (usually an e-mail address).

It looks strange, but it does the trick. See the documentation for labels for more details https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/user-search.html#labels

Answer (score 3):

`is:reviewer AND status:open AND -label:Code-Review=+2`

You can also change the =+2 to >=1.

Comment: That shows reviews which haven't been given a +2, but still includes reviews which I have reviewed as a +1. I am looking for a filter which will show reviews I have not put any code review value on for their latest patchset

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic query, you could use by copy-paste:

```
is:reviewer is:open -is:draft -owner:self -label:Code-Review>=-2,self
```

---

**Description of query:**

- You are added as reviewer
- Commit is open
- Commit is not draft
- You are not an author
- You didn't vote with any label

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this label stuff doesn't work anymore on the latest gerrit. I use this now:

```
is:reviewer is:open -reviewedby:self
```